# Correct way to wrap and dispatch on complicated types

Tags: julia

**TLDR:** What is the safest and simplest way to wrap specific instances of some complicated type `NotMyType` (with many type parameters) into `MyType` such that no performance is lost when dispatching on instances of `MyType` and the type itself `Type{MyType}`?

I will try to give an example of what I am trying to achieve here.

Suppose I intend to wrap a concrete type `GenericType{N, A} <: AbstractGenericType{N}` where `A` can either be `Type1` or `Type2` and `N` is some [value type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#%22Value-types%22). This type is provided by some package Foo.jl. I wish to create a wrapper `PhysicalType` which a subset of say `GenericType{3}`; that is every `PhysicalType` is a `GenericType{3}`, but not every `GenericType{3}` is a `PhysicalType`. I intend to dispatch on `PhysicalType`, otherwise I would have just made a specific constructor.

To me, the most sensible way of specifying `PhysicalType` would be something like

```
struct PhysicalType{T<:GenericType{3}}
    type::T
end
```

Then I can forward all the `GenericType` methods to `PhysicalType` using something like the `@forward` macro from [MacroTools.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/MacroTools.jl/blob/master/src/examples/forward.jl).

However, I also need to forward a function say `Foo.func()` who's argument is of type `Type{<:GenericType}`.  The function `Foo.func` has two methods defined in Foo that look something like,

```
Foo.func(Type{<:GenericType{N, Type1}} = Type1
Foo.func(Type{<:GenericType{N, Type2}} = otherfunc(Type2)
```

I want this function to behave exactly the same for `PhysicalType` as it does for `GenericType`, so I would do something like:

```
function Foo.func(::Type{<:PhysicalType{T}}) where {T<:GenericType{3}}
    return Foo.func{T}
end
```

My question is, there seems to be a lot of redundant information here. Do I need to specify the type of `T` as `PhysicalType` only ever wraps instances of `GenericType{3}`? I also do not want a method defined for every possible instance of `T`, that seems pointless. I only need two methods, one where `T==GenericType{3, Type1}`, and another where `T==GenericType{3, Type2}`.

Would it make more sense to just do something simple like:

```
function Foo.func(::Type{<:PhysicalType{T}) where T
    return Foo.func(T)
end
```

I do not wish to provide the compiler with redundant information (I also do not want to write it if I don't have to), but it is important that I inherit all the performance associated with the methods on `GenericType`. Really I just want `PhysicalType` to behave identically to `GenericType`, but also have the opportunity to dispatch on `PhysicalType` if need be. What is the canonical or most "Julian" way of achieving this?